# copy constructor for a stack class that uses list class

Tags: c++, class, templates

How do you call a copy constructor for template class that has private member which is also another template object

I am building a stack class which uses the list class to build up a stack.
The list class has a copy constructor, 
so I want to copy stack1 = stack2
How do I call it in the copy constructor of the stack copy constructor

The last code is the copy constructor for the stack class and I am trying to copy the private member list_3 myData

When I do myData = src.myData; // It copies the same address and doesn't give a new object

```
template <class ItemType>
            class List_3
            {

            public:


                typedef size_t size_type;

                List_3();

                List_3(const List_3 & src);

                ~List_3();

                void insert(const ItemType & item);

                void remove(); 

                void reset();

                bool advance();

                bool isEmpty() const;

                bool atEOL() const;

                bool isFull() const;

                ItemType getCurrent() const;


            private:

                struct Node {
                    ItemType value;
                    Node* next;
                    Node* previous;
                };

                Node* head;
                Node* tail;
                Node* cursor;

            };

    //Copy Constructor for List class**
    template<class ItemType>
    List_3<ItemType>::List_3(const List_3<ItemType> & src)
    {
        //Copy constructor
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        cursor = NULL;
        Node *tempCursor = new Node;
        tempCursor = src.head; // copying the original list from head to tail
        if (!src.isEmpty()) {   //if the src list is not empty start copy process
            while (tempCursor != NULL)
            {
                insert(tempCursor->value);
                cursor = NULL;
                tempCursor = tempCursor->next;  //Move to the next item in the list use previous if copying from tail
            }
            reset();                            //Reset the cursor
        }



    }


    **//============================================================================**

        template<class ItemType>
            class Stack_3 {
            public:

                typedef int size_type;

                Stack_3();

                //Copy constructor
                Stack_3(const Stack_3 & src);

                void makeEmpty();

                bool isEmpty() const;

                bool isFull() const;

                void push(const ItemType &);

                ItemType pop();

            private:
                List_3<ItemType> myData;

            };

    **//Copy Constructor for Stack Class**
    template<class ItemType>
    Stack_3358<ItemType>::Stack_3358(const Stack_3358<ItemType> & src)
    {

        myData = src.myData;

    }
```

Comment: Read about "constructor initializer list" in your favorite C++ textbook. It goes like this: `Stack_3358<ItemType>::Stack_3358(const Stack_3358<ItemType> & src) : myData(src.myData) {...}`. Having said that, since `List_3` needs a user-defined copy constructor, chances are high it also needs a user-defined copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a initializer list to achieve this

```
Stack_3358<ItemType>::Stack_3358(const Stack_3358<ItemType> & src) 
                     : myData(src.myData) // this calls List_3 copy constructor
{

}
```

`myData = src.myData;` will use the copy assigned operator which will use same address unless copy assignment operator is overloaded.

Comment: This this worked I thought i had overloaded = operator but i check again and there was none.

Answer (score 0):

```
How do you call a copy constructor?
```

You don't call constructor. A constructor runs automatically when you create an object of the corresponding class